# Как отсортировать список с помощью IComparable<>? C#

Tags: c#, .net, сортировка

Всем привет, совсем недавно начал программировать, нужно отсортировать уже заполненные списки. Попробую объяснить структуру:
Есть список Signals, в котором хранятся сигналы, внутри каждого сигнала список с данными, разобрался как это заполнять,но теперь не могу понять как отсортировать данные по Time_ms с помощью IComparable. Вот код:

```
public class Sample : IComparable<Sample>
{
    public float Time_ms;
    public float VarValue;

    public int CompareTo(Sample other)
    {
        // If other is not a valid object reference, this instance is greater.
        if (other == null) return 1;

        return Time_ms.CompareTo(other.Time_ms);
    }
}

public struct Chunk
{
    public List<Sample> samples;
}

public class Signal
{
        public string VarName;
        public List<Chunk> chunks = new List<Chunk>();
}

    // Create a list of signals.
    public static List<Signal> Signals = new List<Signal>();
```

Comment: Пробовали вбивать в поиск по so такое слово как IComparable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Илья, Ваша структура довольна интересна, но всё же Ваш вопрос до конца не понятен.

Вот основные поинты:

**У вас очень сложная древовидная структура**, которая выглядит так:

```
Signals[0].chunks[0].samples[0].Time_ms
```

Есть список сигналов,

каждый сигнал содержит в себе список chunks,

а каждая колода в свою очередь содержит ещё один список -  samples и

**поле Time_ms есть у каждого конечного экземпляра samples** в этом лютом дереве...

Не совсем понятно как вы хотите сортировать Signals по Time_ms, т.к. эти два списка не имеют с собой практически ничего общего - вложенность.

Вполне возможно, что **LINQ Вам поможет**!
Сортируем готовый список по возрастанию

```
    public **class** Chunk
{
    public List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>{};

    void Sort()
    {
        List<Sample> orderedBy = samples.OrderBy(x => x.Time_ms).ToList(); // По возрастанию
        List<Sample> orderedByDescending = samples.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time_ms).ToList(); // По убыванию
    }
}
```

Т.е. ещё раз. 
**Signals - это СПИСОК СПИСКОВ СПИСКОВ** (тройная вложенность) и я не могу лично для себя представить алгоритма его сортировки. Т.е. сортировать список Signals вы можете по публично доступным полям объекта Signal в этом списке, т.к. сортируете объекты Signals(varName, например).
И со struct аккуратней))))

PS: У этого ответа нет цели кого-либо задеть, оскорбить и прочее. Всё происходит от искреннего желания помочь.